# subscription service - email sending

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Am looking for some help in a subscription service email sending from domino using Xpages.

scenario : Paul Goodman is a building contractor and he would like to subscribe to his category named "Buildings and Road”.
When someone asks question about his category "Buildings and Road” he and everyone else that have the same subscription , should get email. I have a LS Agent that goes thought a view to send these emails but I would like
to have his done as soon as the message is saved and it has to send one at the time to void spam filters. I know I could execute the LS agent onSave but do you see another solution maybe with JavaScript ? I have only seen some .NET & PHP solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of options here:

- Extract your logic into a LS library, so it can be used by several agents. Then have on that runs on save (and another one on a new subscription)
- Use a DOTs task to listen to documents save - you can write your logic in Java then
- Call an ?OpenAgent URL from your client side JavaScript
- Put it into your XPage for new articles

Since you have the agent already, I'd go with the first one